# Remove inline search on query result tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, tvos, uisearchcontroller

Ok so I’ve got a resultsController that I am embedding within a SearchController on tvOS (to achieve the inline search functionality). Then I present that within a search container.

```
let searchController = SearchController(searchResultsController: searchViewController)        
let container = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
```

I want to reuse this class to call search functionality without user input. So I want to be able to remove the searchBar and keyboard entirely on certain occasions.

I tried setting searchController.searchBar.hidden to true, but that literally only hides the searchBar, the inline keyboard remains there. How do I hide the inline keyboard, or set the results controller to full screen when results are available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to just present the `searchViewController` attached to the SearchController at all. Just got rid of the container.

The reason it wasn't working earlier is because I lost reference to a delegate I needed to make the search work.